# How to define model parameter value in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

I have a `user` table in which i have multiple roles and i am showing different user on different action by using same `model` `search` `function`. By this

```
public actionAdmin(){
$model = new User('search')
$model->unsetAttributes();
$model->userRole = UmsConfing::ADMIN;
if(isset($_GET('User')))
$model->attributes = $_GET['User'];
$this->render('userlist',arary('model'=>$model));
}
```

I am using this function for different roles .This works well. but now i want to show admin and operation user in same list i tried

```
$model->userRole = UmsConfig::ADMIN || UmsConfig:: OPERATION
```

but i didn't work Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please you can try this below code:

```
public actionAdmin(){
     $model = new User('search')
     $model->unsetAttributes();
       if(isset($_GET('User')))
          $model->attributes = $_GET['User'];

     $this->render('userlist',arary('model'=>$model));
}
```

Below codeadd in **User** Model Search Function:

model/User.php

```
public function search() {
        // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);

        $criteria->addInCondition('userRole', array (UmsConfig::ADMIN,UmsConfig:: OPERATION));

        $criteria->compare('status',$this->status);
        $criteria->compare('is_deleted',$this->is_deleted);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
        'pagination' => array(
            'pageSize' => yii::app()->params->pagesize,
        ),
        'sort'=>array(
                'defaultOrder'=>array(
                        'id'=>CSort::SORT_DESC
                ),
        ),
    ));

}
```

Comment: Thanks for ans but I cant specify these two roles in search function of model because I have many other roles and I am using same model function.

Comment: @mamta Okay i will provide other solution for that.

`$model->userRole = array(UmsConfig::ADMIN,UmsConfig:: OPERATION )`

Comment: Hii thanks I have used your ans createf a new search function in model and added In confition .